# Accessing GeometryReader in values set in makeUIView in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, mapbox, geometryreader

so I have rendered a Mapbox Map using the UIViewRepresentable protocol and the following function:

```
func makeUIView(context: Context) -> MGLMapView {
    
    let map = MGLMapView()
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        map.styleURL = self.mapStyle
        map.delegate = context.coordinator
        map.showsUserLocation = true
        map.attributionButtonPosition = .topLeft
        map.logoViewPosition = .topLeft
        map.logoViewMargins.y = 15
        map.logoViewMargins.x = 95
        map.logoViewMargins.x = 12
        map.attributionButtonMargins.x = 100
        map.attributionButtonMargins.y = 15

        self.configure(map)
    }
    return map
}
```

The only problem is that because I am hardcoding the values for the y margin, the positioning is not ideal across multiple devices. I'd like to use a GeometryReader to access the safeAreaInsets  and then make the y padding a function of that. Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass `GeometryProxy` as argument of view representable constructor, like below

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader {
            DemoView(proxy: $0)
        }
    }
}

struct DemoView: UIViewRepresentable {
   let proxy: GeometryProxy

   func makeUIView(context: Context) -> MGLMapView {
      // use self.proxy.size here
   }

   // ... other code
}
```

Comment: How would I do this for an `ARView`, as an example? I cannot use the simple .frame or .position that I usually associate with SwiftUI views, as you are likely using UIKit views in a UIViewRepresentable. I need to have an `ARView` dynamically update with the values of a `geometryProxy` and I nee it to behave like a SwiftUI view with a `geometryProxy`.